# Get the backtrace of a function call

Tags: vim

To make the `<Fn>` keys more customizable, I use a script (I called it `fkeys.vim`) which creates mappings threw the call of a function (let's call it `Map()`) : the call to this function replaces the use of the `:map` commands in many of my scripts.

It's very comfortable because it lets me add easily some nice features around my personnal mappings, but it brings me a new problem: when I want to know from where a certain mapping is defined, like this:

```
:verbose map ...
```

, then vim always says that **the mapping was last defined in the `fkeys.vim` script, not in the real script where `Map()` is called**. It's logical, but very frustrating, because the `:verbose map` command is very useful, and is the only way I know to find a mapping definition quickly.

One solution would be to add an argument to my `Map()` function, where the filename of the actual script would be passed (in order to store this information and get it back when i need it):

```
function! Map(lhs, rhs, [some other args...], caller)
```

But it would pollute my scripts readability, and it doesn't look very elegant.

Something better would be to be able to **get the backtrace of the function call**, like `debug_backtrace()` in php.

Is it possible with Vim?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It isn't possible to get a *true* backtrace, but if you keep things clean you might be able to get away with parsing `<sfile>`.  According to the manual:

> ```
>               When executing a function, is replaced with:
>               "function {function-name}[{lnum}]"
>               function call nesting is indicated like this:
>               "function {function-name1}[{lnum}]..{function-name2}[{lnum}]"
> ```

Thus something like this should do:

```
function! Backtrace(trace)
    return map(split(substitute(a:trace, '^function ', '', ''), '\.\.'), 'substitute(v:val, ''\m\[\d\+\]$'', "", "")')[:-2]
endfunction
```

You need to call it like this:

```
let callers = Backtrace(expand('<sfile>'))
```

Example:

```
function! F1()
    call Fn()
endfunction

function! F2()
    call F1()
endfunction

function! F3()
    call F2()
endfunction

function! Fn()
    echomsg expand('<sfile>')
    echomsg string(Backtrace(expand('<sfile>')))
endfunction

call F3()
```

Output:

```
function F3[1]..F2[1]..F1[1]..Fn
['F3', 'F2', 'F1']
```

Comment: Tx, so for my case it's not possible to get the filename(s) of the calling scripts. It looks to be some missing feature in vim

Comment: @yolenoyer Not without passing an extra argument.  But if you're willing to go there, `expand('<sfile>:p', 1)` called outside any function returns the current filename.  Alternatively, you could just write wrappers for your `Map()` in all the relevant files, and name the wrappers after the filenames.  As for Vim's API missing crucial functions, well, you must be new to Vim. :)